# TextArea cell renderer for dojo/dgrid

Tags: javascript, dojo, dgrid

I am using dgrid/Grid to define a table structure. **I want the table cells to display multi-line text**. I figured out how to have the cell editor be a TextArea. However, **it's not clear to me how to get the renderer to display multi-line text as well. How do I accomplish this?** This is what I have:

```
editor({label: "First Name", field: "first", sortable: false, editor: getCellEditor, editOn: "dblclick", dismissOnEnter: false})
```

"getCellEditor" is a helper method that returns a **dijit/form/TextArea**. Double-clicking the cell produces a multi-line text area. However, when I finish editing and step off the cell, the cell text reverts to a single line display. Here's the entire grid definition:

```
function getCellEditor() {
    return new TextArea();
}           

// Create a new constructor by mixing in the components
var CustomGrid = declare([ Grid, Keyboard, Selection, ColumnSet, ColumnResizer, editor ]);

var grid = new CustomGrid({
    columnSets: [
        [
            [
                editor({label: "First Name", field: "first", sortable: false, editor: getCellEditor, editOn: "dblclick", dismissOnEnter: false})
            ]
        ], 
        [
            [
                editor({ label: "Last Name", field: "last", sortable: false, editor: getCellEditor, editOn: "dblclick", dismissOnEnter: false}),
                editor({ label: "Age", field: "age", sortable: false, editor: getCellEditor, editOn: "dblclick", dismissOnEnter: false})
            ]

        ]
    ],
    selectionMode: "single", // for Selection; only select a single row at a time
    cellNavigation: true // for Keyboard; allow only row-level keyboard navigation
}, "grid");
```

This is my first JavaScript question, so please pardon any missing / inadequate information. If any other information is needed for you to respond to this question, please let me know.

Answer (score -2):

In renderCell function you may define attribute in textarea widget.

```
function getCellEditor() {
   return new TextArea({
      rows:"5"
   });
}
```

Try this may this help you.

Comment: No. This doesn't help. I don't think you understood my question. I already have a TextArea as an editor (the number of rows it has is immaterial). What I need is a TextArea as the cell *renderer* i.e. I need the cell text to display across multiple lines when the cell is *not* in edit mode.